# I´m able to calculate the mean of a colum, when calling it with $, but not when I call it with [] R

Tags: r

I'm working with a dataframe with 16 colums right? I want to calculate the mean of the values in one of them,

The funny thing is, it only works when I call it using $

```
 mean(datospractica$REGISTRO)
```

[1] 2202

but when I call, the exact same colum using []  I get these.

```
mean(datospractica[1])
```

[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(datospractica[1]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

so, wtf? is it not that $ should be equivalent to [] ? Why does it not work in the second case?

it also does not work like this

```
 mean(datospractica["REGISTRO"])
```

[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(datospractica["REGISTRO"]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

I have double checked, it is the same column, so, why does this happen?

Comment: `datospractica[[1]]` or `datospractica[["REGISTRO"]]`you have to dive into the list (a dataframe is a special kind of list).

Comment: or `datospractica[, "REGISTRO"]` / `datospractica[, 1]`

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [*`The difference between bracket [] and double bracket [[]] for accessing the elements of a list or dataframe`*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/2204410)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `data.frames` are esentially `list`s of vectors of the same length and subsetting `list`s by single brackets `x[]` always returns a `list`. The mean of that is not defined and so it does not work. Instead, you should use the double brackets `x[[1]]` or single bracket `x[,1]` subsetting fuctions.